# Why can't I make the ArrayList static?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, static

I have the following code.

```
public class Start extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    ArrayList<String> aPlayerList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("playerList");
    static ArrayList<Integer> aScores = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("scores");
...
```

I get an error when trying to make the `ArrayList<Integer> aScores` static: `Non-static method getIntent() cannot be referenced from a static context` , and I don't know how to fix this.

If it helps, this is how the intent was passed:

```
            Bundle bund = new Bundle();
            bund.putStringArrayList("playerList", playerList);
            bund.putIntegerArrayList("scores", scores);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Players.this, Start.class);
            intent.putExtras(bund);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Any help would be appreciated, and if you could add the code that would fix it that would be great. Thanks,

Comment: Are there any particular reason for keeping this arrayList static ?

Comment: @android_Muncher Yah, I need to use the values in the arrayList in an onClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your syntax is wrong.

You can't make a variable inside a method `static` what would be the use of this? Static means that the field is related to the class so you can access it without any reference (`ClassName.staticField`).

Variables inside methods are related to the method, so you can't access them outside it so how static could be used here?

Are you sure you don't get confused with `final`? Which is a valid here.

---

To resolve your problem, you just need to make `static ArrayList<Integer> aScores` as field of the class so you can access it anywhere in your code. Then edit your `onCreate` method to this

```
aScores = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("scores");
```

so it will save the array list inside `aScores` field.

Comment: If I use final, would I still be able to change the values in the arrayList using aScores.set(position, newScore)?

Comment: Ehm, even if static was legal `.set` was still possible. What you want is related to mutable and immutable collections. To fix your problem do: `ArrayList<Integer> aScores = Collections.unmodifiableList(getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("scores"));` So you wrap the `ArrayList` inside a unmodifiable list so `set` methods (etc.) will throw you an exception if used.

Comment: But I want to be able to modify the list, that's why I don't want to make it final. I need to to be static so I can use it inside of a for loop that I have later in the code, and I have the .set inside of the for loop. Sorry for this, I'm fairly new.

Comment: Then you need to make static yes, but a static field if you want to make it accessible everywhere. So make a field outside the class and save the reference here. (warning, this approach would let to you more bugs if you are not careful.) Put `public static ArrayList<Integer> aScores` outside the class and inside the `onCreate` method just `aScores = ...`

Comment: outside the method* as field of the class.

Comment: Alright, thanks, you mind editing that into your original solution so I can mark it as the best answer?

Comment: Done, just a hint for your next question: When you post the question write what have you tried and what are you trying to do so next time you will get better answer in less time...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55348/discussion-between-mostafa-saadat-and-marco-acierno).

Answer (score 1):

That is because `getIntent()` is a non static method and should not be referenced to a static field.

**solution:**

Remove the static of your arrayList.

Comment: I need it to be static, is there any way to legally make it static?

Comment: @MostafaSaadat why static?? any reason??

Comment: I need to use it in a for loop later, and I can't think of any other way of doing it. I can't make it final because I want to be able to change the values in the arraylist using .set

Comment: @MostafaSaadat where does the loop located is it in the Start class?

Comment: Yah, it's in the Start class and in OnCreate

Comment: @MostafaSaadat then make your ArrayList<Integer> aScores as a global variable

Answer (score 0):

Static methods get created only once, so you can't reference getIntent() because Java doesn't know which instance of the method you are referencing.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class) for more information on how static methods work.